# tagged type / List - F# Language design

Tags: list, f#, language-design

I read that list in F# are a tagged type with tag ::.

What I don't understand and want to know is that how this should be declared?
Not how I use lists but the formel definition of list in code, or how to define a list in a language where it is not accessible and if is possible to make other tagged types in F# with some kind of encapsulation ([], (), {}, ||,..). Is this strictly a language design?

Comment: There is a duplicate somewhere, but basically :: and [] are cases of a discriminated union

Comment: Nothing to particular about f# for the definition it is very easy to define a similar structure in other languages